# How can I pass a template (slot) from grandparent component down to a grandchild in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm having a case in VueJS 2 where there's a component of 3 level composition (grandparent - child - grandchild) and I need to pass a template/slot from grandparent down to grandchild (being this one `b-table` component from Bootstrap + Vue library (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table)).

#### grandparent component:

```
<template>
  <DataTable
    :tableFields="postFields"
    :tableService="posts"\
  />
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Posts',
    components: {
      DataTable,
    },
</script>
```

#### child component:

```
<template>
  <b-table
    :items="items"
    :fields="tableFields"
  />
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Posts',
    props: {
      tableFields: {type: Array, required: true},
      tableService: {type: Object, required: true},
    },
    components: {
      DataTable,
    },
</script>
```

#### grandchild component:

This one is `<b-table>` from Bootstrap + Vue (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table)

So as Bootstrap + Vue documentation stands for, I can pass a `<template>` down to `<b-table>` but I would like to first pass it from grandparent to child and then from child to `<b-table>`.

Comment: I don't see any slots. Shouldn't there be some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ruy-garcia I got around a similar issue using a property defined in my grandparent. This solution only works if you have a slot where you want to update a few properties in it so it's not that flexible.

```
// Grandparent
<app-table
    :tableFooterLink="{
        link: {name: 'new-player'},
        text: 'Create New Player'
    }"
>
```

Then in the child component checked for the property.

```
// Child component
<vue-good-table>
    <template v-if="tableFooterLink !== undefined" slot="table-actions">
        <router-link class="create-new-player-btn" :to="{name: 'new-player'}">
            {{ tableFooterLink.text }}
        </router-link>
    </template>
</vue-good-table>

export default {
    // stuff
    props: {
        tableFooterLink: {
            type: Object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @stuart-nelson! It makes sense =) Does not look too fancy, but I think it is a current framework's limitation.